# When Upload/download files in window azure vm

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-virtual-machine

I am using dedicated VM for my web application,also use load balance to handle traffic.my query is when I upload updated files ,Will these files accessible to all instance of load balance at once? secondly if users  want to download files   from application,will they download from actual VM or any instance of load balance will help user to download these files,whatever the instance be user hits.

Answer (score 0):

> when I upload updated files ,Will these files accessible to all
>   instance of load balance at once?

If you upload files from the LB public IP, we can't access all instances of load balancer at once, **a session can only assess to a instance.**
By default, we upload files to all instances via the intranet.

> if users want to download files from application,will they download
>   from actual VM or any instance of load balance will help user to
>   download these files,whatever the instance be user hits.

Do you mean user download files from actual VM or one of the instances?
There are two modes with Azure Load Balancer, Hash-based mode and source IP mode. The session will access to different instance in different mode.
If we download the files from load balancer public IP address, we will access to one instances of the load balancer (Hash-based).
If we configure the Load Balancer in source IP mode, we will access to the instance even if the instance be user hits.
Azure Load Balancer will load balance incoming Internet traffic to virtual machines (the instances of load balancer), the default distribution algorithm is a 5-tuple hash to map traffic to available servers.
[image]
More information about Azure Load Balancer, refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-distribution-mode).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: What can I do for you?  If the answer was helpful, please don't forget to mark it as an answer, thanks.